# ServerName for local Apache2 instance

Tags: apache, ssl

I wanted to create my own self signed SSL certificate and add it to the local Apache2 instance (i.e. changing http://localhost/ to https://localhost/). However, I'm stuck at the part on what to put under the server IP in default-ssl.conf file. I'm referring to [this resource](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) to create the SSL certificate.  I tried putting "127.0.0.1", "localhost" and the private IP address (in this case it's 10.0.2.15) under the "ServerName" part. However, it's still failing with the following error.

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13) Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to addres 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Can anyone please give some hints on what went wrong? I'm running out of ideas (or things to google) why the server name is wrong...

The first few lines of my default-ssl file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin temp@temp.com
    ServerName localhost
```

Comment: You can ignore the warning about ``ServerName``. The other error indicates you already have some other web service using port 80. Do you already have nginx running on the system as well?

Comment: I just googled it and found nginx... Do I need to stop that to enable SSL?

Comment: You can not set two service listening the same port. Disable :80 on one of the two servers. About ServerName is convenient to set the hostname chosen for your certificate

Comment: For a self signed certificate, especially if accessing via localhost anyway, doesn't really matter that doesn't match. If coming in using localhost, they would need to be the first ``VirtualHost`` for 80/443 found anyway, as name based virtual hosting doesn't work when using localhost in URL and will use first ``VirtualHost`` for port.

Comment: I have added the first few lines of my default-ssl file code. ServerName is set as localhost at the top but not sure why it didn't work. I don't have a VirtualHost section for port 80. Should I add that?

Answer (score 0):

Ironically the issue seems to have resolved by itself... Not too sure what happened but now I'm facing another issue (which I posted on [Unable to change the document root of https://localhost/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792524/unable-to-change-the-document-root-of-https-localhost))

I kept the code as it is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin temp@temp.com
    ServerName localhost
```