# Unable to change the document root of https://localhost/

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ssl

I went to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` and updated the document root when it is accessing ssl. However, for some reason, it's still pointing to `/var/www`. I have reloaded and restarted apache2 server using `sudo service apache2 reload` and `sudo service apache2 restart` but the changes are still not reflecting. Are there other places that I need to change to make the `https://localhost/` points to `/home/student/public_html`?

The first few lines of default-ssl:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin temp@temp.com
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/student/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/student/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

The first few lines of default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/student/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/student/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    Redirect "/" "https://localhost/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all browser history and it starts working now. :)